# How Sync and Async works at same time

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka first time to process real time messages.

Using `Sync` offset, message would be `comitted` or `failed to commit` before receiving next message from broker. And in case of `ASync` offset, next message will be recieved no matter last message is `commited` or `still pending` to be comitted.

```
try {
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            System.out.printf("topic = %s, partition = %s, offset = %d,
                customer = %s, country = %s\n",
                record.topic(), record.partition(),
                record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        }
        consumer.commitAsync(); 1
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Unexpected error", e);
} finally {
    try {
        consumer.commitSync(); 2
    } finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
}
```

But lets say If I use both `Sync and ASync` both at the same time like above example, how it'll work ?

For example, In a poll If I get 5 messages having offset from `1 to 5`, and out of that `1 and 2` got processed and committed too. But from `3 to 5` offsets got processed but not committed, for the same request sent by `ASync` but got stuck somewhere in network.

All commit requests will be sent from ASync to broker already but committed `1 and 2` only, then control comes to Sync in `final` part. Where it will try to commit all `Not-Committed` messages one by one until it gets failed or Succeed. But if it gets failed at 3rd offset only, then in rebalance, from where it will start reading ?

- How latest and earliest will play their part ?
- If property is set to `latest`, then consumer will consider which message to be latest in broker after rebalancing ? Becasue `3, 4, 5` will be there already which are processed but not committed plus some more new messages lets say `6, 7, 8` offsets. Which one will be latest ? 3rd onwards or 6th onwards ?
- If property is set to `earliest`, then consumer will consider which message to be earliest in broker after rebalancing ? From which offset consumer will start reading the mesaages ?

Answer (score 0):

The finally block will only ever be reached when there's an exception within the while loop, so only one commit type is ever happening at a time

Also note that you're committing full batches, not one by one within the for loop, with the default max.poll.records=500, then that's the most offsets you'd be committing at any point

> How latest and earliest will play their part
>   This only applies when no previous group exists.

If a group exists and rebalances, it always resumes from existing offsets, not uses this property

Comment: lets assume I've moved my ASync into for loop, then it will be sending request to commit after every message processing . Correct .. ? Secodnly, what do you mean that latest and earliest only works with no groups ? Can you please explain more for my example ?

Comment: If you move, then yes, though it still doesn't stop the logic of the exception handler and finally block only execute once. Have you read the description of `auto.offset.reset` property in the docs? It only applies if no consumer group exists (meaning no offsets were ever committed yet).